# There are precisely seven open sets in a topological space on a finite set X. What is the minimum possible cardinality of X?

Tags: general-topology

> There are precisely seven open sets in a topological space on a finite set $X$. What is the minimum
> possible cardinality of $X$?

Can anyone help me to solve this question.
I think there is no rigorous formula to find it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I can't approach... please help me

Comment: Try to find a topological space that has exactly seven open sets. This will give you an upper bound on the size of possible cardinalities.

Answer (score 1):

If $X=\{0,1\}$, $|\mathcal P(X)|=2^2=4$, which is insufficient.

If $X=\{0,1,2\}$, $|\mathcal P(X)|=2^3=8$. But consider the set $\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\}\}$ of cardinality $7$. This is not a topology as it is missing $\{0,2\}\cap\{1,2\}$. Similar arguments show no other set can be dropped individually instead.

So let $X=\{0,1,2,3\}$, and consider $\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{0,1,2\},\{0,1,2,3\}\}$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak Not at all. He gets a different answer from yours.